# Is there any way to run the SQL queries on SQL Server 2000 using Command Prompt

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2000, sqlcmd

Is there any way to run the SQL queries on SQL Server 2000 using command prompt. I just done a google search and understood that there is a command called `SQLCMD`, but this is only applicable to SQL Server 2005 +.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For SQL Server 2000, the tool was called `osql`.

See [the official TechNet docs on how to use it](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa214012%28v=sql.80%29.aspx)